# Finding a prime number at least a 100 digits long that contains 273042282802155991

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I am new to Java and one of my class assignments is to find a prime number at least 100 digits long that contains the numbers 273042282802155991.

I have this so far but when I compile it and run it it seems to be in a continuous loop.

I'm not sure if I've done something wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(304877713615599127L);
    System.out.println(RandomPrime(y));
}

public static BigInteger RandomPrime(BigInteger x)
{
    BigInteger i;

    for (i = BigInteger.valueOf(2); i.compareTo(x)<0; i.add(i)) {
        if ((x.remainder(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))) {
            x.divide(i).equals(x);
            i.subtract(i);
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Try adding some `System.out.println()` statements to discover the values of `x` and `i` in your loop. It'll be enlightening.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find prime numbers this large with any brute-force approach. Also, I'm not sure what RandomPrime is supposed to do.

Comment: @emory - no, it's an infinite loop - but I didn't want to give too much away.  I'm pretty sure sarnold sees what is happening.

Comment: a number is prime if it is indivisible by all primes less than its sqrt.

Comment: @ziesemer you are right.  It is infinite.  But more importantly even if it was changed slightly so that it did terminate, it does not come close to meeting spec.  304877713615599127L is way less than 100 digits long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is homework ...

1. There is a method on BigInteger that tests for primality.  This is much much faster than attempting to factorize a number.  (If you take an approach that involves attempting to factorize 100 digit numbers you will fail.  Factorization is *believed to be* an NP-complete problem.  Certainly, there is no *known* polynomial time solution.)
2. The question is asking for a prime number that contains a given sequence of digits when it is represented as a sequence of decimal digits.
3. The approach of generating "random" primes and then testing if they contain those digits is infeasible.  (Some simple high-school maths tells you that the probability that a randomly generated 100 digit number contains a given 18 digit sequence is ...  82 / 10<sup>18</sup>.  And you haven't tested for primality yet ...
4. But there's another way to do it ... think about it!

Only start writing code once you've figured out in your head how your algorithm will work, and done the mental estimates to confirm that it will give an answer in a reasonable length of time.

---

<sub>When I say infeasible, I mean infeasible for you.  Given a large enough number of computers, enough time and some high-powered mathematics, it *may* be possible to do some of these things.  Thus, technically they *may* be computationally feasible. But they are not feasible as a homework exercise.  I'm sure that the point of this exercise is to get you to *think* about how to do this the smart way ...</sub>

Comment: Tiny factual correction: Factorization hasn't been proven to be NP-complete or NP-anything for that matter. But you are correct that there is no known polynomial time algorithm. (and it haven't been proven/disproven that no polynomial algorithm exists either)

Comment: Can you use the BigInteger.probablePrime method and attach that number to it somewhere in like a system.out.println statement?

Comment: @James Ward you could use probablePrime but Stephen C suggests that it would take too long.  If you could test 1,000,000 numbers per second and Stephen C's probability calculation is correct, I figure you could turn in your homework in about 26,000 years.  When is your homework due?

Comment: @JamesWard - you *should* use `BigInteger.probablePrime()`.  But you need to use it the *right* way.  Generating random numbers, testing if they are prime and testing if they contain the digit sequence is not the right way.  There's a smarter way.

Comment: @JamesWard - if you want another hint - how do you generate strings that contain a given substring ... without testing?

Comment: @Stephen C.  probablePrime does not test for primality.  It generates a random (probable) prime of a specified size.  So I don't think it is possible to use probablePrime in combination with your hint about generating strings that contain a given substring.  There is another method that works perfectly with that hint to produce a 2 line solution.

Comment: @emory - my mistake.  I confused `probablePrime` with `isProbablePrime`.  It is the latter that he should use!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I am finally starting to get somewhere with this. I think I need to use a while loop with isProbablePrime. I am trying to work out the equation I need to get the number I am looking for. I have a starting number that is 100 digits long by taking a BigInteger number and making it into a string.

Comment: @James Ward.  You can use isProbablePrime for an acceptable solution, but there is an even better solution.  I just wrote a 1 line program that solves the problem in less than one second.  HINT:  which of BigInteger's methods probably uses a while loop with isProbablePrime thus saving you programming effort?

Comment: Would it be the BigInteger method probablePrime?

Comment: No, a probablePrime solution would take about 26,000 years to complete.  Using isProbablePrime should take less than one second of computer time but you have to write a bunch of code to figure out the first prime greater than a specified BigInteger - (which in my opinion is an acceptable solution).  If there was an existing method that could determine the first prime greater than a specified BigInteger, you would not have to write and then debug so much code (which would be even better).

Comment: @emory thanks I'm a newbie at programming just started out as a computer science major. The prof is pretty tough but I do enjoy it.

Answer (score 4):

One tip is that these statements do nothing:

```
x.divide(i).equals(x);
i.subtract(i);
```

Same with part of your `for` loop:

```
i.add(i)
```

They don't modify the instances themselves, but return new values - values that you're failing to check and do anything with.  `BigIntegers` are "immutable".  They can't be changed - but they can be operated upon and return new values.

If you actually wanted to do something like this, you would have to do:

```
i = i.add(i);
```

Also, why would you subtract `i` from `i`?  Wouldn't you always expect this to be 0?

Comment: i = i.add(i) would be 2,4,8,16,32,64,... Probably better to do i=i.add(TWO) where TWO is an appropriately defined constant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement/use miller-rabin algorithm

[Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)

chapter 4.24
http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf

Comment: Ummm ... BigInteger already implements a Miller-Rabin based primality test.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: the SO's problem is figuring out a solution using the existing primality test method that runs in a reasonable time.  The answer may be obvious to you, but he is a beginner, and this is homework.  See my answer ... and the comments ... to understand where the OP is coming from.